# MacBook Pro 8.1 (13") WiFi issues

Tags: wireless, macbook, apple

I know that this has been asked before but I have a problem connecting.

I've installed all updates and Ubuntu 11.10 through UEFI on my MacBook Pro (no MBR booting).

I've gotten the WiFi card recognised and to see networks but when I select mine it tries to connect but constantly asks for my password over and over again.

I used Ubuntu's help guide to install 11.10 on this MacBook I got everything else working except for the WiFi.

Comment: Please post the output of both lsmod | grep ath and lspci

Comment: Ubuntu is not longer installed on this laptop but I'm planning on reinstalling I will post after its reinstalled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomend following the guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2/Oneiric#Wireless)

The guide tells you to add a ppa as this driver does not appear to have the best version in the kernel or something.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpodroid/mactel

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-instal
```

After you have installed these you need to install the linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic via

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic
```

Unless, if you have the pae kernel installed (you would know if you do), the linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic-pae package. (as the guide says)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic-pae
```

Next you should edit a couple files

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Once that is open add the line

```
blacklist ndiswrapper
```

next edit one more file with

```
gksudo /etc/pm/config.d/modules
```

make sure the wireless modules (b43 and bcma) are blacklisted (takin from guide)

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="b43 bcma"
```

After you install the drivers as discribed in the steps above and edit some files,you can reboot by rebooting your normal way, or simply keeping your terminal session open and typing:

```
sudo reboot
```

Again, this is all taken from the guide I linked in the first sentence, so if this does not make sense, feel free to look there as well.

Comment: some of the text was cut off

Comment: thanks help a lot now I just gotta reinstall Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro again! lol