# Help getting wireless working on MacBookPro8,1

Tags: installation, wireless, hardware, macbook-pro

I have practically no idea of what I'm doing, but I've installed Ubuntu on my MacBookPro8,1 primarily because I needed to use Octave and I figured I might as well try out the whole thing here. Anyway, I tried to follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120143/macbook-pro-8-1-13-wifi-issues) but I get the following error when I try to enter

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic-pae
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic-pae  
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic-pae'
```

I'm not sure what this means or what I can do from here.

**EDIT** as per Vivek's answer, here are the details of **/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
colin@Biff:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
```

Comment: Did you add the `ppa:mpodroid/mactel` as specified in [that answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120143/macbook-pro-8-1-13-wifi-issues)

Comment: Also do you have pae kernel? If you don't you should install `linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic` instead

Comment: please share your details of **/etc/apt/sources.list** looks like the apt repositories are not properly configured.

Comment: Can you tell me how I would do that?

Comment: open terminal : CTRL + SHIFT+ t
;


cat /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: you can also download the .deb and install : http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/oneiric/main/base/linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic-pae

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: @blvdeer yes I did do that, and no you're right I should be installing the generic one. But I get the same error either way.

Comment: I tried installing the .deb and got the following `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic:
 linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic depends on linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-3.0.0-30-generic; however:
  Package linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-3.0.0-30-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic
`

Comment: If you are running Quantal as indicated above, you need: linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic; not oneric. What wireless card are you trying to install? lspci -nn | grep 0280.

Comment: What does this tell us? dmesg | grep b43

Comment: @crf Listen to chili555. :) We need more hardware information. And use a proper backported compat-wireless package for your release. The answer you were referring to is for 11.10 only, but just needs adjustments on the package to pick.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of you way overthinking.

First fix your packages

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Let it do it's thing.

Next in Ubuntu 12.10 the wireless "just works" but you likely have to install the proprietary driver.

Go sit next to your router and plug in the old fashion way. Then run `sudo apt-get update`.

When that is finished run 'jockey-kde' you may need to install it.  Then just activate your wireless driver from the list.

That should be all there is to it. jockey will take care of the rest. It should have popped up when you fist started the computer, but I don't see any easy way to run it if you missed the alert. Just run it from terminal instead.

Side note, you may want to plug in and run apt-get update before apt-get -f install, but that's up to you. If your running 12.10 you should not need any kind of backported driver the wireless nic in the 8.2s has worked well from 11.something forward.